# Jython in parasoft SOA

Tags: multiple-columns, jython

I'm using jython scripting with a datasource.  Datasource columns are `MR1`, `MR2`, `MR3`.

Here is my script.

```
x=float(context.getValue("datasource", "MR1"))
y=float(context.getValue("datasource", "MR2"))
z=float(context.getValue("datasource", "MR3"))
input1 = ((1+x/float(100))*(1+y/float(100))*(1+y/float(100)))-1
return SOAPUtil.getXMLFromString([str(input1)])
```

I'm using `x`, `y` and `z` as variables.. there are many columns maybe more than 50 for each column I cant declare a variable like `x`, `y` and `z` for each column... So, what I'm trying to do is get the column count and iterate the column and row through `FOR` loop.

I checked the help contents and there is no columncount method for this tool.

Can you please help me with this script.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the tool but maybe can you try to access the context value. and if the result is null then this column doesn't exist. Just itereate until there is no data in your value.

Comment: But if there is an empty cell value the script would fail right?

Answer (score 1):

In java with selenium automation also, we do NOT have column count. navigation takes place with rowcount and rowdata ONLY. But we have getLastColumnNum. However with jython i'm not very sure as i have just started working with it...please try something equivalent-maybe like lastcolumn....

Comment: Hi Jayanth- so are you using parasoft soa?

I figured out a way to have it working with the column count 

Columncount=somenumber 
Index =1 ( column names as 1,2,3 so on)

While Index <= columncount
x=float(context.getValue("Datasource ", str(index))) # for iterating every cell value through column
Index = index +1

Thanks all for the replies